# Package 'lib32ncurses5-dev', 'lib32z1-dev' has no installation candidate

Tags: 12.04, package-management, chromium, source

I'm trying to build blink(content_shell) on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit and I am stuck on `build/install-build-deps.sh`. I think I have tried every single solution that I found on stackoverflow

**Error Log:**

```
It produces the following output:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package lib32ncurses5-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package lib32z1-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lib32ncurses5-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'lib32z1-dev' has no installation candidate

You will have to install the above packages yourself.
```

**/etc/apt/source.list:**

http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/8505008/

**What I've tried: (not in order)**

```
1. sudo apt-get install lib32z1-dev
   -> package 'lib32z1-dev' has no installation candidate
2. sudo apt-get install lib32z1-dev:i386
   -> package 'lib32z1-dev' has no installation candidate
3. Ubuntu Software Center > Software source > change to 'main server'
```

[image]

```
4. sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
   -> still the same :(
5. sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   -> dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture
6. apt-file search lib32z1-dev
   -> no output
7. manually download and install from http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/lib32z1
   -> still the same error log
8. update depot_tools
9. sudo apt-get install lib64ncurses5 lib32ncurses5-dev lib32z1-dev
```

> rna@rna-P580:~/workspace/src$ sudo apt-get install lib64ncurses5 lib32ncurses5-dev lib32z1-dev
>      Reading package lists... Done
>      Building dependency tree
>      Reading state information... Done
>      Package lib32ncurses5-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>      This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>      is only available from another source
>
> Package lib32z1-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>      This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>      is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'lib32ncurses5-dev' has no installation candidate
>      E: Package 'lib32z1-dev' has no installation candidate

```
10. Response to @Eliah Kagan's suggestion

 Logs for `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev`: 
 -> zlib1g-dev was already there, libncurses5-dev was newly installed
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8511253/

```
 Logs for build/install-build-deps.sh:
 -> but when I run install-build-deps script I had the same 'Error Log'
```

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8511268/

```
 Instruction from: 
 -> What I am trying is really simple, get the chromium code then build content_shell.
```

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions

```
11.
```

Comment: yeah I'm editing right now

Comment: 32bit. `$ uname -m` returns `i686`

Comment: then why would `depot_tools` required to install that package? hmm getting confused :(

Comment: is `uname -m` proper way to check 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: the package you are trying to install is for 64 bit ubuntu

Comment: yep, and what was the result?

Comment: it returned 'i686'

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=434264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***TL;DR:*** `sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev`

You seem to have attempted two kinds of things:

- To install special for a 64-bit system that provide 32-bit libraries (so 32-bit programs can run). These special packages don't exist on a 32-bit system--the regular libraries are 32-bit.
- To enable multiarch and install 32-bit packages on a 64-bit system. But [multiarch is enabled by default in 12.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch) already. Plus, you don't need multiarch to install 32-bit packages on a 32-bit system.

Whatever instructions or suggestions you've been following appear to be directed at users of 64-bit Ubuntu systems. But since `uname -m` produces `i686`, you have a 32-bit Ubuntu system.

Therefore, you should just install the regular 32-bit versions of the software for your 32-bit system. This is considerably simpler than anything you appear to have attempted so far.

The packages you probably want are:

- [zlib1g-dev](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/zlib1g-dev) [image] ([package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/zlib1g-dev), [32-bit file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/zlib1g-dev/filelist))
  Provides files like `libz.a` and `libz.so`, [corresponding](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/lib32z1-dev/filelist) to [`lib32z1-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/lib32z1-dev).
- [libncurses5-dev](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications//libncurses5-dev) [image] ([package page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libncurses5-dev), [32-bit file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/i386/libncurses5-dev/filelist))
  Provides files like `libcurses.a` and `libcurses.so`, [corresponding](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/lib32ncurses5-dev/filelist) to [`lib32ncurses5-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/lib32ncurses5-dev).

One way to install these packages is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev
```

<sub>(If that doesn't fix the problem, then more information will be needed about the problem itself. Almost all the details you've provided pertain to what happened when you tried to solve it, rather than the problem you're trying to solve. In particular, the full output of running `build/install-build-deps.sh`, or of whatever build command causes that to be run, would be helpful, as well as a detailed description of what instructions you've been following, if any, and *all steps* done so far to obtain and attempt to build the software. *But I suspect installing those two packages will just fix it. Or at least get your further through the build.*)</sub>

Comment: I appreciate your input Eliah, unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem. I posted the result and full output of `build/install-build-deps.sh` on 'What I've tried' #10

Comment: @RNA What happens if you *don't* run `install-build-deps.sh`, but just try to proceed with the build?

Comment: I'm running `gclient sync` It will take about an hour. I will share the whole process and the result when it's done